# Tree Vuedraggable, Cannot drag node to the nodes that don't have child

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, tree, drag

I cannot drag a node to the nodes that don't have a child. It works fine on my nested tree code:

```
<div class="child">
            <draggable 
                :list="trees.childs" 
                :options="{animation: 200, group:'dragtree'}"
                :move="onMove"
                @end="onEnd">
                <graph
                    v-if="open"
                    v-for="tree in trees.childs"
                    :key="tree.root"
                    :trees="tree">
                </graph>
            </draggable>
        </div>
```

It doesn't work on a node which doesn't have a child.

When I tried to drag the node and want to drag to that node which doesn't have a child, it doesn't work. I also use two methods i.e onEnd and onMove, which works but it makes 2 copy whenever I drag that element:

```
onEnd:function(event){
        this.D_related.childs.push({root : this.D_dragged.root, depth : this.D_related.depth+1, childs: this.D_dragged.childs})
    },
onMove: function(event){
        console.log("Move", event)
        this.D_dragged = event.draggedContext.element
        this.D_related = event.relatedContext.element
        return 
    },
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.